# Rails grouped select field not showing selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have Rails form for a model called `Car` with a grouped select field for the `:location` attribute, which I created using `grouped_options_for_select` form helper. The problem I am having is that when I want to edit a `Car` which I have saved to the database, the value stored for the `:location` attribute - `:location_id` is not shown in the select field as the selected value. Instead the select field shows up blank with no value selected. I have other select fields on the form which are not grouped and do not have this problem. My form helper looks like

```
<%= car_info_field.select :location_id, grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_locations),
          { include_blank: true }, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

My model looks like

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    validates :location_id, presence: true
```

How can I get the grouped select field to show the right selected value on the edit form?

Comment: I think you need to add attr_accessible for your location_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grouped_options_for_select` helper is not aware of the form builder and you need to pass the "key to select" explicitly.

```
grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_locations, car_info_field.object.location_id)
```